# How do I create dynamic panel to be shown and hide using difference choices in combo box in C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, combobox, panel, nbug

I want to make a GUI which is dynamic, meaning that the GUI will change depending on the choice which user makes on the combo box.

For example, if combo box consists of {English, Spanish, French}, the panel on the bottom of the combo box will change its description language depending on the choice.

To do this, I believe I have to do something like clear panel then redraw panel, but I have no idea how.

Can someone tell me how to make this happen in details on Visual Studio 2005 C#?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you have inside your panel ?

Comment: I made a window form which contains a panel that has a combo box. Inside panel, it has a combo box which you can select from 3 languages, and below it there's another panel which has choices, and I want to change the panel according to the language user chooses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this exact implementation right here: http://nbug.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6081#107027 which implements an IPanelLoader (ISubmitPanel for my case) interface and loads any panel with the same name of that in a combo box. Basically download the source code and compile it and have a look at the "Configurator" project. There are a lot of things which would take me pages to explain but there is already a full blown example.

In my case, any form implementing the `ISubmitPanel` interface (MailForm, FtpForm etc. in my case) can be loaded like this:

```
private void SubmitComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (this.submitComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "E-Mail":
            this.Controls.Add(new MailForm());
            break;
        case "FTP":
            this.Controls.Add(new FtpForm());
            break;
        case "HTTP":
            this.Controls.Add(new HttpForm());
            break;
    }
}
```

Ofcourse this code should run in another form where you want to load the other form into.

[image: Dropdown to load panels]

[image: E-Mail panel loaded]

Edit: The source code is from [NBug](https://github.com/soygul/NBug) project.

Comment: +1 to you.  I think I read the question incorrectly, and your answer is much better than mine was.

Comment: Incredible. This will help me alot thank you! I will let you know after I read your codes and see if I understand them all :D

Comment: Note that the source code is changing rapidly, so naming in my examples may not be %100 accurate (like I've change MailForm into Web.Mail) but I'm sure that you'll find your way around since classes and files always remain where they are and naming scheme is crystal clear.